# How much tax on net zero income?

Tags: taxes

I start an S Corp in January and borrow 1 million dollars. By the end of the year I manage to make 1 million dollars and repay the loan pocketing zero dollars. How much tax do I have to pay this year?

Key information from the comments:

> Q: if you used the $1 million you made to repay the loan, what
> happened to the $1 million you got from the loan itself? You still
> have that money (or assets you bought with it), right?
>
> A: I spent the money on salaries. No assets accumulated. Next year I
> may have to borrow money again

Comment: "pocketing zero dollars" -- if you used the $1 million you made to repay the loan, what happened to the $1 million you got from the loan itself? You still have that money (or assets you bought with it), right?

Comment: I spent the money on salaries. No assets accumulated. Next year I may have to borrow money again.

Comment: That is important info to include. So you had revenue (sales) of $1 million, expenses (salaries) of $1 million, and profit of zero. The loan is mostly irrelevant.

Comment: If you made 0 net profit how did you pay back the $1M loan?

Comment: borrowed $1M + receivables $1M - salaries $1M - loan payback $1M = $0

Comment: @Charles L: So if you paid out $1 million in salaries, that's a valid business expense.  So you had $1 million gross income - $1 million business expenses, that leaves you with zero net income, no?

Comment: @CharlesL You're conflating asset/liability accounts with revenue/expense accounts. Tax is paid on net income (revenue - expenses) only, not borrowing or paying back money. Borrowing money is not revenue, and paying it back is not an expense.  So the only taxable things you have are whatever generates the $1M you used to pay salaries, which nets to zero in your example.

Comment: Put another way, if you borrowed $1M and did _absolutely nothing with it_, then you'd have no "revenue" and hence no tax. The borrowing and paying back has no impact on taxes in general.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Paying back a loan is not an expense - only the *interest* would be an expense. The rest would be profit that is taxable.

If you used the $1M profit to pay salaries, and paid back the $1M from the cash that remained, then you'd have zero net income and pay no taxes.

Comment: See OP comment clarifying that there were actual expenses (salaries) of $1 million in addition to the loan payments.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting from this [Bankrate article](https://www.bankrate.com/loans/small-business/write-off-repayment-of-business-loan/):

> Are business loan payments tax deductible?
>
> In short, business loan payments aren’t tax deductible. When a
> business loan is received by a company, it’s not included as taxable
> income. In turn, when that loan is repaid, you are not able to deduct
> loan principal payments. You are simply paying back money you
> borrowed, not income spent.
>
> That doesn’t mean that there aren’t deductions you can still make.
> Interest paid or accrued on your business loan are tax deductible in
> most cases.

So no, you can't deduct payments that go towards paying off the principal of the loan, but you can usually deduct the interest payments. If you have an S-corp and are worried about this, talk to a tax accountant.